# Passing Jquery object to function not working for IMG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass Jquery object to function but its not working for IMG tag.

I made below example.When I click on the text it works , But when I click on image its not working.

```js
$(document).on('click','.playvid',function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    popup($(event.target));
}); 
function popup(data)
{
    data.html("success");   
}
```

```css
.playvid 
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-id="3ZdHRvPNyCI" class=" playvid" ><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconset-addictive-flavour/png/button_green_play.png">WATCH DEMO</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because, depending on where you click, `event.target` can be the `img` element, which cannot contain `html`. Instead, pass `$(this)` to your function as that will contain the `.playvid` element:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.playvid', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  popup($(this));
});

function popup(data) {
  data.html("success");
}
```

```css
.playvid {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-id="3ZdHRvPNyCI" class="playvid">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconset-addictive-flavour/png/button_green_play.png">
  WATCH DEMO
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the object by `class` -

```
popup($('.playvid'));
```

For multiple `.playvid` class -

```
popup($(this));
```

Comment: I have multiple playvid class

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.playvid',function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();

 popup($(event.currentTarget));

    });
```

where currentTarget is all the time the last warping object of all objects having '.playvid' as rule.